# How to hide navigationbar when showing dialog in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose

I hided the navigationbar in jetpack compose.
But, when i show a dialog, the navigationbar also shows.
I want to hide the navigationbar when showing the dialog.
Please see GIF animation for details

Please let me know if you have a good idea.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            SampleComposeTheme {
                var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                OutlinedButton(
                    onClick = { showDialog = true }
                ) {
                    Text("Button")
                }

                if (showDialog) {
                    AlertDialog(
                        onDismissRequest = {},
                        text = {
                            Text("Alert")
                        },
                        confirmButton = {
                            Button(onClick = { showDialog = false }) {
                                Text("ConfirmButton")
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        window.insetsController?.apply {
            hide(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
            systemBarsBehavior =
                WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you find solution for this? Having the same problem when using Popup

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google's Accompanist library which provides utilities for updating the system UI bar within Compose.[Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/)

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:<version>"

val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
        systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false // Status bar
        systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = false // Navigation bar
        systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false // Status & Navigation bars
        systemUiController.navigationBarDarkContentEnabled =false
```

Comment: Even though it works on the "activity" screen, it does not work using the Material "Dialog" composable. At least not here :(

Answer (score 1):

We can additionally use WindowInsetsController for SDK > 30, have to add SDK check using IF or @Requires

```
window.insetsController?.apply {
    hide(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
    systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE //keeps hidden and on swipe transparent bars are shown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: looks like its still can behave strangely on older Android versions

The dialog lives in a different Window than the activity, so you'll need to call rememberSystemUiController from within the Dialog content to do so.

```
@Composable
fun TutorialDialog(
    tutorial: Tutorial,
    onAck: () -> Unit
) {
    Dialog(
        properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = false,
            dismissOnClickOutside = false,
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
        ),
        onDismissRequest = { }
    ) {
        TutorialView(
            tutorial = tutorial,
            onAck = onAck
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TutorialView(tutorial: Tutorial, onAck: () -> Unit) {
    val systemUIController = rememberSystemUiController()
    systemUIController.isNavigationBarVisible = false
    systemUIController.isStatusBarVisible = false

    // composable code here
}
```